# Set max value for second handler in Jquery UI slider handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-slider

After years using STOFLW, for first time i havent found the answer on a first sight. So, lets go:

I have a jquery UI slider range, lets say from -5 to 5. I want to set the second handler maximun to 0 after the first one is moved to a positive value (actually the first handler is already forced to select only positive values).

Another way to ask the question is "Can I force one of the handlers to select only psoitive values and the other only negative ones"

Regards and BTW, thousand of thanks to everyone here, you saved me tons of minuts.

Comment: create a fiddle of what you've got so var http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it already. I've edited the post with the solution that I've found.

Comment: A bit hard to read that solution but if your happy with it and no one downstream has to maintain your all good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, i've edited the post and made a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/santirisco/mPNsC/3/

```
$( ".slider-form").slider({
            values: [0,0],
            min: -5,
            max: 5,
            step:.5,
            animate: true,
            create: function(event, ui) {
        //On Create create an array to store the values of each handler
                hndlrpos=[];
            },
            stop: function( event, ui ) {
        //On Stop store the values of each handler
                for (i=0; i<=$('.ui-slider-handle').length; i++){
                    hndlrpos[i]=ui.values[i]
                }
            },
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
        //ON Slide return false if we are overpasing the limits, 
        //this part shuold be improved but by now it's working
                if( (hndlrpos[0]!== undefined && hndlrpos[0]>0&&(ui.values[1])>0)
                    ||
                    (hndlrpos[0]!== undefined && hndlrpos[0]<0&&(ui.values[1])<0)
                    ||
                    (hndlrpos[1]!== undefined && hndlrpos[1]>0&&(ui.values[0])>0)
                    ||
                    (hndlrpos[1]!== undefined && hndlrpos[1]<0&&(ui.values[0])<0))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The documents  say 
        min: 300,
        max: 2500,
    step: 100,
    value: 500,

My example I use for my own.

```
$("#slider-impulseH").slider({
orientation: "hortizonal",
range: "min",
min: 300,
max: 2500,
step: 100,
value: 500,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    $( "#engineI" ).text( ui.value );
    }
change: function( event, ui ) {
 $( "#engineI" ).text( ui.value );
 }
});
```

Documents for max in a slider [slider](http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#option-max).

Comment: I have a good github example but I am using it for some serial work with a node server to drive a tank over wireless; but here you go for the code examples [My git for sliders example](https://github.com/alexmac131/NodeXbeeTank)

Comment: Wow! Awesome tank!! That seems great. Anyway that's not exactly what i needed. The issue was: I have two handlers, if one is moved to a value greater than 0 the other can only be moved to a value lower tha 0 and vice-versa (of course if any of the handlers is moved to 0 you can move the other anywhere). I've already found the solution, here is: http://jsfiddle.net/santirisco/mPNsC/3/  Thanks anyway (or should i saud Tanks ;) )

Comment: you can have lots of handlers and layers of them, though I am still learning to register events I do manage it in my github code.  I am very glad I could help, remember to accept the answer so I can get credit. There is another in my git on cloning, if your interested as well (unrelated to what your doing now)